# Why does the Xlib specification does not use pointers to struct Window?

Tags: c, xlib

Although otherwise working with pointers, all Xlib functions I've seen so far pass their Window struct by value, not by reference. E.g.:

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XGetClassHint.html

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XDestroyWindow.html

Is there any particular rationale for that? In particular, in the case of XGetClassHint, the first and third parameters are passed by reference but the second isn't.

Comment: `Window` is a server-side thingamabob, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Window` in those examples isn't a struct; it's just an unsigned long.  That is, given:

```
#include <X11/X.h>
Window w;
```

If I pass that through `gcc -E` I see:

```
$ gcc -E wintest.c | grep Window
typedef XID Window;
Window w;
```

And `XID` is:

```
$ gcc -E wintest.c | grep XID
typedef unsigned long XID;
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Window` is a beast that lives on the X-Server, not on the client. The only thing that is needed on the client is an identifier that uniquely addresses the real window on the server. That is not a structure, but rather a *handle*, or an `XID`.